# Testing value with IF in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

My company has tasked me to convert my department's database from MySQL to SQL Server Express (2018, I believe) I have extensive experience in MySQL but this is the first time I've more than dabbled in SQL Server.

It appears that using IF to test a value may not be supported. In this typical code sample, the IF is part of a larger expression. If it's necessary to use CASE WHEN ELSE how do I embed that within a function?

In MySQL:

```
SET course_dir = kappa + IF(kappa > 90,-1,1) * kappa_rot
```

Answer (score 2):

`SQL Server` is using `IIF` function. See [details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**syntax**

```
IIF ( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )
```

**your query**

```
SET course_dir = kappa + IIF(kappa > 90,-1,1) * kappa_rot
```